# Enable checkbox when the user has scrolled to the bottom of a T&C page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, checkbox

- my html sample div class :

  ```
  <div id="terms">
      <p>
           Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam lacinia est non cursus rutrum. Donec vulputate tincidunt mollis. Aenean elementum adipiscing lorem. Sed vitae volutpat ante. Aliquam pretium sem arcu, ac consequat enim blandit eget. Integer posuere arcu vulputate nisi interdum dignissim. Sed quis tortor risus. Vivamus leo lectus, ornare sed vehicula quis, hendrerit eu mi. Curabitur pulvinar luctus nibh, ut laoreet dolor venenatis et. Curabitur eu nulla congue, iaculis tellus sit amet, blandit lorem. Vestibulum rhoncus non augue eu cursus. Etiam neque neque, commodo id accumsan ac, auctor nec nunc.
      </p>

      <p>
           Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam lacinia est non cursus rutrum. Donec vulputate tincidunt mollis. Aenean elementum adipiscing lorem. Sed vitae volutpat ante. Aliquam pretium sem arcu, ac consequat enim blandit eget. Integer posuere arcu vulputate nisi interdum dignissim. Sed quis tortor risus. Vivamus leo lectus, ornare sed vehicula quis, hendrerit eu mi. Curabitur pulvinar luctus nibh, ut laoreet dolor venenatis et. Curabitur eu nulla congue, iaculis tellus sit amet, blandit lorem. Vestibulum rhoncus non augue eu cursus. Etiam neque neque, commodo id accumsan ac, auctor nec nunc.
      </p>
      <p>
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam lacinia est non cursus rutrum. Donec vulputate tincidunt mollis. Aenean elementum adipiscing lorem. Sed vitae volutpat ante. Aliquam pretium sem arcu, ac consequat enim blandit eget. Integer posuere arcu vulputate nisi interdum dignissim. Sed quis tortor risus. Vivamus leo lectus, ornare sed vehicula quis, hendrerit eu mi. Curabitur pulvinar luctus nibh, ut laoreet dolor venenatis et. Curabitur eu nulla congue, iaculis tellus sit amet, blandit lorem. Vestibulum rhoncus non augue eu cursus. Etiam neque neque, commodo id accumsan ac, auctor nec nunc.
      </p>

  </div>

  <input id="payment" type="checkbox" disabled name="terms"> <span class="redSmall">I agree to terms and conditions</span>
  ```
- my css :

```css
#terms {width: 780px;height: 150px;overflow-y: scroll;border:2px solid #ccc;}
```

Can someone tell me the JS or JQuery for enabling the checkbox when the user has scrolled to the bottom of the T&C page ? I have tried other answers too but none of them worked. The checkbox remains disabled whatever I do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Im not a Jquery Expert but just by googling I created this example. I hope it helps!

```js
jQuery(function($) {
  $('#terms').on('scroll', function() {
    if ($(this).scrollTop() + $(this).innerHeight() >= $(this)[0].scrollHeight) {
      $('#payment').removeAttr("disabled")
    }
  })
});
```

```css
#terms {
  width: 780px;
  height: 150px;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  border: 2px solid #ccc;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="terms">
  <p>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam lacinia est non cursus rutrum. Donec vulputate tincidunt mollis. Aenean elementum adipiscing lorem. Sed vitae volutpat ante. Aliquam pretium sem arcu, ac consequat enim blandit eget. Integer
    posuere arcu vulputate nisi interdum dignissim. Sed quis tortor risus. Vivamus leo lectus, ornare sed vehicula quis, hendrerit eu mi. Curabitur pulvinar luctus nibh, ut laoreet dolor venenatis et. Curabitur eu nulla congue, iaculis tellus sit amet,
    blandit lorem. Vestibulum rhoncus non augue eu cursus. Etiam neque neque, commodo id accumsan ac, auctor nec nunc.
  </p>

  <p>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam lacinia est non cursus rutrum. Donec vulputate tincidunt mollis. Aenean elementum adipiscing lorem. Sed vitae volutpat ante. Aliquam pretium sem arcu, ac consequat enim blandit eget. Integer
    posuere arcu vulputate nisi interdum dignissim. Sed quis tortor risus. Vivamus leo lectus, ornare sed vehicula quis, hendrerit eu mi. Curabitur pulvinar luctus nibh, ut laoreet dolor venenatis et. Curabitur eu nulla congue, iaculis tellus sit amet,
    blandit lorem. Vestibulum rhoncus non augue eu cursus. Etiam neque neque, commodo id accumsan ac, auctor nec nunc.
  </p>
  <p>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam lacinia est non cursus rutrum. Donec vulputate tincidunt mollis. Aenean elementum adipiscing lorem. Sed vitae volutpat ante. Aliquam pretium sem arcu, ac consequat enim blandit eget. Integer
    posuere arcu vulputate nisi interdum dignissim. Sed quis tortor risus. Vivamus leo lectus, ornare sed vehicula quis, hendrerit eu mi. Curabitur pulvinar luctus nibh, ut laoreet dolor venenatis et. Curabitur eu nulla congue, iaculis tellus sit amet,
    blandit lorem. Vestibulum rhoncus non augue eu cursus. Etiam neque neque, commodo id accumsan ac, auctor nec nunc.
  </p>

  <p>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam lacinia est non cursus rutrum. Donec vulputate tincidunt mollis. Aenean elementum adipiscing lorem. Sed vitae volutpat ante. Aliquam pretium sem arcu, ac consequat enim blandit eget. Integer
    posuere arcu vulputate nisi interdum dignissim. Sed quis tortor risus. Vivamus leo lectus, ornare sed vehicula quis, hendrerit eu mi. Curabitur pulvinar luctus nibh, ut laoreet dolor venenatis et. Curabitur eu nulla congue, iaculis tellus sit amet,
    blandit lorem. Vestibulum rhoncus non augue eu cursus. Etiam neque neque, commodo id accumsan ac, auctor nec nunc.
  </p>

  <p>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam lacinia est non cursus rutrum. Donec vulputate tincidunt mollis. Aenean elementum adipiscing lorem. Sed vitae volutpat ante. Aliquam pretium sem arcu, ac consequat enim blandit eget. Integer
    posuere arcu vulputate nisi interdum dignissim. Sed quis tortor risus. Vivamus leo lectus, ornare sed vehicula quis, hendrerit eu mi. Curabitur pulvinar luctus nibh, ut laoreet dolor venenatis et. Curabitur eu nulla congue, iaculis tellus sit amet,
    blandit lorem. Vestibulum rhoncus non augue eu cursus. Etiam neque neque, commodo id accumsan ac, auctor nec nunc.
  </p>

</div>

<input id="payment" type="checkbox" disabled name="terms"> <span class="redSmall">I agree to terms and conditions</span>
```

Answer (score 1):

use below script,

```
<script>
$( document ).ready( function() {
 $('#terms').scroll(function () {
  if ($(this).scrollTop() == $(this)[0].scrollHeight - $(this).height()) {
    $('#payment').removeAttr('disabled');
    }
 });
});
</script>
```

here is runnable demo : https://jsbin.com/cajusebera/edit?html,js,output

Comment: The checkbox is still disabled buddy.. didn't work. Anyways, thanks for the answer

Comment: @SiddharthSingh check demo